# serialization of entity model c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, serialization, entity

I am getting this error from time to time with serialization and I don't know which file I need to serialize. 
The pages are on and off one time they load other time they don't. 
Here is the error I am getting:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize the session
>   state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize
>   the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or
>   MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies
>   if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in
>   'Custom' mode. --->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_CC06DC79809AC788823D74B88F94CCB7155ADCE697911AF73214FB8B5F2B2EB4'
>   in Assembly 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Nop.BusinessLogic,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked
>   as serializable.     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type)     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context)     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>   at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value,
>   BinaryWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value,
>   BinaryWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object
>   value, BinaryWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData
>   item, Stream stream)     at
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData
>   item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]& buf, Int32& length, Boolean
>   compressionEnabled)     at
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext
>   context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean
>   newItem)     at
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object
>   source, EventArgs eventArgs)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

So basically what I think is something with the entity model but I want to know how I can serialize that.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: does this cover it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276507/serializable-classes-and-dynamic-proxies-in-ef-how

Comment: Do you need to serialize the whole entity? It may be better to just store the unique ID in the session and retrieve the entity itself from the database.

Comment: btw, does `DataContractSerializer` work with your object? If so, another option would be: serialize with `DataContractSerializer` and just store the output

Comment: +1 for data contract serializer.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? This kind of errors are usually symptoms of something that could be done right in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product (Error with this class)

Should add **[DataContract]** attribute on class and **[DataMember]** on fields like that

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[DataContract]
public class Account
{
    [DataMember]
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public System.Guid AccountSubTypeID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> IndustryTypeID { get; set; }
}
```