# Entity Framework Model with Table-per-Type Inheritance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

When I define a model in Entity Framework with Table-per-Type Inheritance, if I have a base class/table (not abstract) called person, and two sub entities and tables, adult and child, after creating a child, how would I take the same object and convert it to adult? Once converted to adult, the child record should be deleted, though the base class data in the person table should be retained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. It is similar problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266848/downcasting-with-entity-framework). Simply the entity exists and its type is immutable. The only way to do that is delete child entity (= records from both tables) and create a new adult entity (= new records for both tables).

This doesn't look like scenario for inheritance at all.

Edit:

The comment about inheritance was targeted for scenario where you mentioned `Person`, `Adult` and `Child` entities. Anyway once your scenario allows changing the type you should think about another solution where the part which can change will be handled by composition.

For example:

```
public class DataSource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DataSourceFeatures Features { get; set; }
}

public class DataSourceFeatures
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("DataSource")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DataSource DataSource { get; set; }
}

public class XmlDataSourceFeatures : DataSourceFeatures { ... }

public class DelimitedDataSourceFeatures : DataSourceFeatures { ... }

public class ServiceDataSourceFeatures : DataSourceFeatures { ... }
```

Now changing a type means deleting dependent current `DataSourceFeatures` from the database and create a new one but original object remains the same - only relation changes.

Comment: I have a base class named Datasource and a few derived classes: XmlSource, DelimitedSource, ServiceSource, etc. Each derived class have specific properties to it, while they all share common fields: name, description, etc. Are you saying that from a perspective of storing data in a Db it doesn't look like scenario for inheritance? I've also considered serializing each derived classes properties and storing them in the Datasource table, but I'd rather work with tables for now instead of XML. In my case a user may change Datasource type from XML to Delimited, thats where my question came from.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I like your approach. I didn't think of it this way originally, though I certainly think this works better.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do this with EF, because with inheritance you've created an object-oriented abstraction over table relationships that doesn't allow you to convert from different types. In OO you can't do thing like this:

```
Child child = new Child();
Adult grownUp = child;
```

And then expect the child to be an adult. You'd do it like this:

```
Child child = new Child();
Adult grownUp = child.GrowUp();
```

So assuming you're using SQL Server you could do that with a stored procedure. Something like GrowUp(child) and have it create a new entry in the Adult table as well as delete the entry in the Child table, but leave Person untouched. You could return the new adult object from the procedure. This can then be used like this:

```
Adult grownUp = context.GrowUp(child);
```

However you'd need to make sure in your code that after this line you don't use the child object anymore and you probably need to refresh or remove it from the context (not entirely sure about this).

Comment: I like your thinking here. To take this idea a step further, I could use generics to cast the derived object to its base class and than instantiate a new derived class. Of course derived class properties will always be lost as they're specific to child classes, but that's fine. Additionally I could use generics to remove the old derived object and record from the db, and create a new one with new derived class.