# EF Code First Map 1 to 0 w/ inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

EF 4.1

I have Product Table, the product can be different types such as lets say Shirt and Pants. I believe this is referred to as a SuperType and SubType

> Products (1..1:0) ProductShirt
>
> Products (1..1:0) ProductPants

e.g.

```
Products
--------
ProductId (PK)
Product Name
Product Type (1 or 2, let's say 1 is Shirt, 2 is Pants)

ProductShirtType
----------------
ProductId (PK, FK)
HasShortSleeves
etc....

ProductPantsType
----------------
ProductId (PK, FK)
IsCargoPants
etc...
```

I am trying to model this in EF CF and Table Per Type (TPT) matches these requirements. The problem I am having is the user can change product types and according to this answer by Ladislav Mrnka, that is not possible and should instead favor composition:

[Entity Framework Model with Table-per-Type Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328386/entity-framework-model-with-table-per-type-inheritance)

Which is great, so now my models look like this:

```
public class Product {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int ProductType { get; set; }
  public virtual ProductSubType SubType {get; set;}
}

public abstract class ProductSubType {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
}

public class ProductShirt : ProductSubType {
  public bool HasShortSleeves { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPants : ProductSubType {
  public bool IsCargoPants { get; set; }
}
```

I am at a loss on how to map the abstract type and subtypes. And just as important how I go about changing from one product type to another.

Comment: Are the tables something you defined or they are pre-defined and cannot be changed? Why do you need to change from one product type to another? How come a shirt is becoming a pants?

Comment: @Pawel the tables are not predefined. The product type is just an example, but in the real use case this is perfectly valid. In the case of converting, what we would end up doing is discarding the "shirt" specific values and allow changing the product type to "pants"

Comment: Then I am not sure if your design is valid. In C# if you have an object of type A you cannot just convert it to an object of Type B - you would need to create a new object B and copy what's applicable. If you want to be able to change object type you may be better off having a flag to indicate what kind of object it is. In this changing the type would be changing the flag. I assume that objects have the same properties. If they don't then I don't think they are easily convertible.