# Excluding a property from EF storage

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, annotations

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327939/options-for-class-design-using-safe-downcasting), someone suggested an interesting approach to a problem I'm trying to solve.  the solution included adding a property to one of my classes, a class that is generated by the Entity Framework.

Is there any way to exclude this new property from being stored by EF?  so I have something like:

```
public partial class User
{
    UserState state; // property I do not want stored in the database
```

where `User` has a bunch of properties defined elsewhere by EF?

thanks - e

Comment: i'm probably missing the main point, but if a property is just added to the class, would the entity framework store it without explicit mapping in the EDMX?

Comment: hmm... that's a good question.  I assumed it would be stored but perhaps it isn't...

Comment: perhaps your confusing it with n/hibernate?

Comment: why did I get a down vote? is my question unclear? unuseful? what?

Comment: @Gabriel, no.  I don't use n/hibernate and don't know anything about it...

Comment: anyway, i can confirm that EF will not store things unless they are mapped to a storage entity explcitly, you can extend the partial classes as you wish without fear

Comment: your question was fine, everybody is a different level of expertise - anyway if you get a down vote and no comment to go along with it, just shrug it off.. it's not worth worrying about

Comment: @Gabriel, I have that happen to me often and I lose reputation but there's never feedback on why...  anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as per @Gabriel above, I need not worry, properties are not automatically stored.